# Django send email formatting issues

Tags: django, email

I'm experiencing a formatting issue when sending a form output to email in Django 1.8. The output includes two tabs for each statement in the delivered in plain text email. How do I remove the tabs or ensure the output is to the far left?

Here is an example of the output. I receive this in email every time:

```
    Business: DS2   

    Location: 
sdad
sdasd
sadasd 


    Description: 
sdasd
asd
asd


    Host Ticket: None

    System Ticket: None

    Created By: user
```

Below is my views.py

```
class NotifyCreate(CreateView):
model = Notify
template_name = "notify/add.html"
fields = [
    "priority",
    "business",
    "location",
    "description",
    "host",
    "system",
]


def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):    
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    priority = form.cleaned_data.get("priority")
    business = form.cleaned_data.get("business")
    location = form.cleaned_data.get("location")
    description = form.cleaned_data.get("description")
    host = form.cleaned_data.get("host")
    system = form.cleaned_data.get("system")
    subject = "%s Notification"%(priority)
    message = """
    Business: %s 
    \n 
    Location: %s 
    \n  
    Description: %s
    \n 
    Host Ticket: %s
    \n  
    System Ticket: %s
    \n  
    Created By: %s
    \n
    """%( 
        business, 
        location, 
        description,
        host,
        system,
        self.request.user)
    from_email = 'donotreply@_.com'
    to_email = 'user@_.com'
    if subject and message and from_email and to_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_email], fail_silently=False)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return super(NotifyCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

If possible, I would like the output to be like a standard plaintext email..

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly recommend that you use 4 spaces instead of tabs for indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the multiline string, you shouldn't indent the beginning of each new line, because that whitespace is included in the string. It should be:

```
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        message = """
Business: %s 
\n 
Location: %s 
\n  
Description: %s
\n 
Host Ticket: %s
\n  
System Ticket: %s
\n  
Created By: %s
\n
"""%( 
    business, 
    location, 
    description,
    host,
    system,
    self.request.user)
```

If you think that looks ugly, you can use [`ddent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent)

```
from textwrap import dedent

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        message = dedent("""
        Business: %s 
        \n 
        Location: %s 
        \n  
        Description: %s
        \n 
        Host Ticket: %s
        \n  
        System Ticket: %s
        \n  
        Created By: %s
        \n
        """ % (...))
```